# Is there an existing library to parse JSON to Dictionary<String,Object> in .net?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I'd like to be able to parse a string of JSON representing an object into a property bag (like a Dictionary) which I can use in C#.

Given this string:

{ "id":1,  "name":"some name",  "some parameter":2 }

I want to end up with a Dictionary which contains "id", "name", and "some parameter" as keys and 1, "some name", and 2 as values respectively.

I don't want to parse the JSON string myself - maybe there's a library (preferably in the .net framework) that I can lean on to do the parsing for me to give access to the key/values in the JSON object. Or is there a deserializer available which I can explicitly tell which .net type to target?

In my scenario I'll only ever have one root "object" (it won't start with an array).

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer() { MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue };
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)json.DeserializeObject(yourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

[JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) should do what you need.

Also, [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) if you don't mind going 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) and [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to see if either of those meet your needs?

If not, you could also try [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I'd seen the DataContractJsonSerializer, but hadn't seen the JavaScriptSerializer (as used in Fisher's answer.) Thanks.