# How to extract data from JSON in ASP.NET using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

```
{"pometek.net":{"status":"available","classkey":"dotnet"},"pometek.com":{"status":"available","classkey":"domcno"}}
```

I want to dispense this in table format. Need help.

Comment: You can deserialize it to `IDictionary<string, string>`, take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981364/is-there-an-existing-library-to-parse-json-to-dictionarystring-object-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need a third-party library; the out-of-the-box [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) can handle this.

```
class Item {
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string classkey { get; set; }
}

var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
var input = "{\"pometek.net\":{\"status\":\"available\",\"classkey\":\"dotnet\"},\"pometek.com\":{\"status\":\"available\",\"classkey\":\"domcno\"}}";
var results = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, Item>(input);
var query = results["pometek.net"].status; // = "available"
```

Displaying this as a table is a separate step.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to deserialize the json object into a C# class, and then map that class to a table format in asp.net