# Using Dynamic types with JSON in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. I am trying to hit an external web service from the controller in my app. Currently, I am hitting the web service like this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

  var response = await client.GetAsync(GetServiceUrl());
  dynamic data = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(...)
}
```

The result from the web service can have three different schemas in JSON. They look like this;

**schema 1**

```
{
  "request":"some info",
  "value": [
    {"id":1, name:"bill" },
    {"id":2, name:"john" }
  ]
}
```

**schema 2**

```
{
  "request":"some info",
  "value": [
    { "orderId":"A12345", orderDate:"10-12-2014" },
    { "orderId":"B31234", orderDate:"11-01-2014" },
    { "orderId":"C36512", orderDate:"12-03-2014" },
  ]
}
```

**schema 3**

```
{
  "request":"some info",
  "value": [
    { "productId":"11-22-33", "name":"ball", "description":"a round thing" },
    { "productId":"3A-12-52", "name":"tire", "description":"keeps you moving" },
    { "productId":"7D-xy-23", "name":"plate", "description":"something to eat off of." },
  ]
}
```

I would like to avoid writing three separate classes if at all possible. I really only want to do two things: 1) count the number of objects in the `value` array. 2) Loop through the objects in the `value` array and print out some of the values via Razor.

Can I do these two things without creating 3 new classes? If so, how?

THank you!

Comment: Will a `Dictionary<string, Object>` suffice?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981380

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `json.net`, you can use `JObject` and `JArray`.

```
var json = @"{'value': [ { 'id' : 1}, { 'id' : 2 } ]}";
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var values = (JArray) jObject["value"];
Console.WriteLine("Number of items: {0}", values.Count);

foreach (var value in values)
{
    // do something with value.
}
```

If you're not using json.net, you could go with Robert Harvey's suggestion and use `JavaScriptSerializer`.

```
var jsonDict = serializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, object>>(json);
var array = (IEnumerable<object>) jsonDict["value"];
```